# How to auto scroll to another page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two file in index and profile. I want to go to profile page and directly to section faq by automate scrolling

My index

```
<a href="profile.html">Go</a>
```

My Profile

```
<section id="home" style="height:500px;background:red">
<section id="name" style="height:500px;background:yellow">
<section id="faq" style="height:500px">
```

Is it possible when I click from homepage directly to id="faq" in profile page?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that:

At first give a name in anchor tag something like that in `profile.html` page in preferred location where you want to scroll:

```
<a name="jumpHere">somewhere</a>
```

And then set link location like following:

```
<a href="profile.html#jumpHere">Go</a>
```

Right now click on expected element you can trigger top link or on write something like following:

```
$("#faq").click(function(){
    window.location = 'profile.html#jumpHere';
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't `name="jumpHere"` be `id="jumpHere"`?

Comment: @Tinsten no this is should name because this is hash link.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an anchor link `profile.html#faq` to jump there, do not need jQuery, if you do not need scolling animations.

But if you do, you need jQuery to handle that:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```